# How to focus cursor at the end of text in ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, angular-material

This is below code:

```
var oldData = this.ckEditor.getData();
this.ckEditor.setData(oldData + "{" + data + "}")
```

after this how to focus cursor at the end of text in `ckeditor 5`
I am using `angular 5` and `ckeditor 5`?

Comment: Quick response on this will be appreciated

Comment: In version 4 there was method ckeditor.inserthtml(updateddata); it automatically shifts the cursor at the end of new updated text but in ckedior 5 I can only find setData and neither .focus() function is there to achieve this. So I require the possible way in ckeditor 5 to achieve this

Comment: Waiting for reply on this. Any one.